# Windows phone 8 animated page transition such as android with ViewPager

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, transition

In wp8 (and wp7) there are 5 types of page transitions: RollTransition, RotateTransition, SlideTransition, SwivelTransition, TurnstileTransition.

But i want make transition between pages like Android transition use control ViewPager.

Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks.
But i didn't get to make transition like an Android.
can i realize transition like a this?
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. I could not make such a transition in which the data from two different pages AT THE SAME TIME will be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For doing Custom Animation you can use storyboard class in wp8 as well as windows 8.And if you want do it in simple way you have to use Microsoft Blend for VS 2012. In which you have to open your project in blend and make new storyboard that you can call in your project. you can see this storyboard in XAMLpage.

Comment: yes you can do it. i am working on it and nearly can make any transition what i want but you have you have to be precise about the position of controls on storyboard time line. the are basic easing functions also .After start recording choose control and expand it then click on rendertransform then you will see in right windows thr is option for selct an easing function.